# How to quote a left quote inline?

Tags: support, markdown

How can I type a left quote inside an inline quote? For instance, how can I quote the following snippet from the TeXbook: [image: left quote] inline?

- If I use a single left quote: `\catcode`\{=1`
- If I use a double left quote: ``` \catcode``\{=1 ```
- If I escape the left quote with a backslash: `\catcode\`{=1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want *two* backticks

```
``\code`\{=1``
```

Comment: ``Tha`nks!`` (giving it a try)